# Is It Possible to SMS an Image Using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

As you are fully aware PHPMailer let us to send SMS (text message) through SMS Providers. Now I just wonder if it is possible to send Image Message through the PHPMailer library or not? If not is there any other solution to do this? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: An SMS cannot contain an image, since it is limited to a few bytes of length. That's why it is called a "text message", why SMS is short for "short message service". So this is not possible. Not because of limitations of php or phpMailer, but because of the techical limitation of the carrier implementation of the Telcos.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions would be using a service such as Plivo or Twilio to send the messages.

Or if using an Email => SMS gateway then you would store a copy of the image on your system and send a link in the SMS.